# how can I use pandas dataframe with out of bounds datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a dataframe like this:

```
housing_deals.head()
Out[2]: 
         price   sale_date 
0  477,000,000  1396/10/30 
1  608,700,000  1396/11/25 
2  580,000,000  1396/10/03 
3  350,000,000  1396/12/05 
4  328,000,000  1396/03/18
```

how can I convert sale_date column to pandas datetime
i see below
[How to work around Python Pandas DataFrame's "Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265288/how-to-work-around-python-pandas-dataframes-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp)
but yet i cannot do that for my dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert values to daily periods, check [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans):

```
df['sale_date'] = df['sale_date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='D'))
print (df)
         price   sale_date
0  477,000,000  1396-10-30
1  608,700,000  1396-11-25
2  580,000,000  1396-10-03
3  350,000,000  1396-12-05
4  328,000,000  1396-03-18
```

EDIT: You can convert values to numbers and then use function with [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans):

```
print (df['sale_date'].str.replace('/','').astype(int))
0    13961030
1    13961125
2    13961003
3    13961205
4    13960318
Name: sale_date, dtype: int32


def conv(x):
    return pd.Period(year=x // 10000,
                     month=x // 100 % 100,
                     day=x % 100, freq='D')
  

df['sale_date'] = df['sale_date'].str.replace('/','').astype(int).apply(conv)
print (df)

         price   sale_date
0  477,000,000  1396-10-30
1  608,700,000  1396-11-25
2  580,000,000  1396-10-03
3  350,000,000  1396-12-05
4  328,000,000  1396-03-18
```

Comment: it gives me this error : day is out of range for month because i have day with value of 31 in my dataframe how can i handle this?@jezrael

Comment: @saeedzali - What is your pandas version?

Comment: it is '1.0.5' @jezrael

Comment: @saeedzali - problem is with data `housing_deals.head()` ? All with all data? It means working `df['sale_date'].head().apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='D'))` and not `df['sale_date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='D'))` ?

Comment: @saeedzali - ok, if upgrade to last version I hope help.

Comment: i run it on google colab but it gives me same error @jezrael

Comment: i am sorry to take your time. now i want to convert it to datetime to resample it by day but i can not thanks for your answer @jezrael

Comment: @saeedzali - The best post new question if not working `df = df.resample(freq='d', on='sale_date').sum()`

Comment: i post it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185179/how-can-i-resample-pandas-dataframe-by-day-on-period-time @jezrael

Comment: i changed the url. now you can comment there. previous post is closed.@jezrael

Comment: link is here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731501/how-can-i-resample-pandas-dataframe-by-day-on-period-time @jezrael